# finder is very slow to show files in yosemite 10.10.3

Tags: macos, finder

After the update to Yosemite 10.10.3 finder takes a long time to show the files.
MacbookPro Core i7 8GB, HD120GB solid, 15G free

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a very, very slow Finder. After looking around on the Internet I just started trying different things.

This worked for me:

1. Make sure you have a backup using Time Machine (I did not need it, but you better do it in case...).
2. Open Disk Utility and check the Macintosh.
3. It showed different problems in my case, and wasn't able to repair it using Disk Utility. Therefore follow the next steps.
4. Restart your laptop holding <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> until the Apple logo appears.
5. Choose to repair the disk.

Answer (score 0):

This could be entirely normal and transitory or it could be something you need to resolve.

To start, open Activity Monitor and quit all the apps you have running except it. Watch for 60 seconds and then make a screen shot of the window for reference.

- Command Shift 4 - the cursor changes to a cross
- press Space - the cursor now snaps the window
- click on the activity monitor window

Grab snaps of CPU / Memory / Energy and then again 5 minutes later.

If Finder is still slow - post your results and/or let us know if you need help deciphering what Activity Monitor is doing. Based on what's busy (or what's not busy) - you can then dig into which Finder folders and views are not snappy.

Comment: Also - for me. I pay attention to Memory Pressure alone. What tasks are using is almost never important unless you have pressure and want to know what apps to tune or quit. Under Energy - I sort by Avg Energy Impact descending. CPU I sort by % descending. Also be sure the View is All Processes